# PHP Regex Match From Variable

Tags: php, regex, variables, match

I am trying to regex match dates & times from a php 7.2 variable.

The data with datetime is coming right out of a database query.  There is some search and replace then happening on the data for display purposes, but I have tried matching data before and after the search & replace.

```
$textdescription = $row['TEXT_DESCRIPTION'];
$search = array('#$#', '<(>', '<)>', '[');
$replace = array("\r\n", " ", " ", "\r\n\r\n[");
$ticketnotes = str_replace($search, $replace , $textdescription);
echo nl2br(htmlentities($ticketnotes, ENT_QUOTES));
```

This displays the description just fine.. but now I am trying to pull out dates & times from this data.

Example of $textdescription as an short example is:

```
    03/13/2020 18:04:50 WJG
    [Question] - Still Having Issues
    [Environment] - NA
    [Answer] - I explained
    [Next Steps] - ANSWERED

    03/07/2020 15:18:58 JAG
    [Question] Startup Questions
    [Environment] series
    [Answer] Customer sees 
    [Next Steps] Completed
```

My php code looking for the two datetime matches above are:

```
$re = "/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/";
preg_match_all($re, $textdescription, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

the $matches returns nothing.  If I copy the above $textdescription variable, and manually place it into a variable in the code, everything matches as expected.  Only when retrieving it from the db I get no match.  I have also tried $ticketnotes instead of $textdescription with no success.

I hope its something simple I overlooked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure, your dates and times always have 2 digits, even when the first is zero? Might be worth checking

Comment: before you run preg_match_all, maybe just check some code above has not mangled it, print_r etc.. btw works for me  https://3v4l.org/bQlIh

Comment: Regex works with provided example. https://3v4l.org/c0A6K You could simplify regex to `~\d\d/\d\d/\d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d~` Unless you need matching for every value. `\d\d` is shorter than `\d{2}`

Comment: There is a space, one or more? Is it a Unicode space? Try `$re = "/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})\s+(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/u";`

Comment: Is the date always at the beginning of that text and in the same format? If so, a simple substring of fixed length could get it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the leads and ideas.

Turns out the $textdescription shows in the browser window no problem, but looking at the source of the output (using Ctrl+U), I see the dates MM\DD\YYYY and the time are separated much further than in the browser window.  I counted the spaces, and changed the regex.

The working code is as follows:

```
$re = "/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})          (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/";
```

It had 10 spaces.  So in summary, when matching regex, even a space makes a difference, and output in a browser window does not always match whats in code.

Comment: The amount of whitespace could vary. Might want to use `\h+` which is one or more horizontal whitespace.